# Sheafication of a presheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

I have to solve exercise 2.3 by Shafarevich - Basic algebraic geometry, vol. II.

Let $X$ be a topological space, $M$ an Abelian group and $\mathfrak{F}(U)$ the quotient group of all locally constant functions on $U$ with values in $M$ by the constant functions; for $U \subset V$, $\rho_U^{V}$ is restriction. Prove that $\mathfrak{F}$ is a presheaf and determine its sheafication.

It's easy to prove that $\mathfrak{F}$ is a presheaf, because of the properties of restrictions and of locally constant functions.
Now, I know that sheafication is the family of germs $\{ u_x \in \mathfrak{F}_x\}_{x \in U}$ such that for all $x \in U$, there exists a neighbourhood $x \in W \subset U$ and an element $w \in \mathfrak{F}(w)$ such that $u_y=\rho_y^{W}(w)$ for all $y \in W$.
At a first glance, I think it's the set of locally constant $M-$valued functions, but I'm not sure of this and I can't give a proof of t his fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C} (U)$ be the set of constant functions $U \to M$ (where $U \subseteq X$ is open and $M$ is considered to have the discrete topology) and let $\mathscr{L} (U)$ be the set of locally constant functions $U \to M$. It is not hard to see that $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{L}$ are presheaves on $X$. By definition, we have the following short exact sequence of *presheaves*,
$$0 \to \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{L} \to \mathscr{F} \to 0$$
so the induced sequence of *sheaves* is also exact:
$$0 \to \tilde{\mathscr{C}} \to \tilde{\mathscr{L}} \to \tilde{\mathscr{F}} \to 0$$
Hence, $\tilde{\mathscr{F}} = 0$ if and only if $\tilde{\mathscr{C}} \to \tilde{\mathscr{L}}$ is an isomorphism. I leave it to you to show that $\tilde{\mathscr{C}} \to \tilde{\mathscr{L}}$ is indeed an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

$$\mathcal F^{sh}=0{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, can you prove your assertion, please?

Comment: Dear Federico, above all I wanted to correct your erroneous conjecture . The problem should be easier now that you know what you have to prove. In case of difficulty you might consult sections 3.3 and 3.4 of Tennison's book (http://books.google.fr/books/about/Sheaf_Theory.html?id=oRs7AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) for the most explicit treatment of those questions that I know about.